# Filter sharepoint system folders at root level

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Is there any way to filter system folders when retrieving via REST from Sharepoint online?

From MSDN documentation retrieving all folders at root level using http://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/folders I cannot find a way to discriminate system from custom folders.

I also try filter by folder properties but no luck finding a property that may helps.

As an example I get folders like this:

```
Exists = 1;
Files = {
      "__deferred" = {
            uri = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')/Files";
                    };
                };
Folders = {
      "__deferred" = {
            uri = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')/Folders";
                    };
                };
IsWOPIEnabled = 0;
ItemCount = 1;
ListItemAllFields = {
      "__deferred" = {
            uri = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')/ListItemAllFields";
                    };
                };
Name = SiteCollectionImages;
ParentFolder = {
      "__deferred" = {
            uri = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')/ParentFolder";
                    };
                };
ProgID = "<null>";
Properties = {
      "__deferred" = {
            uri = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')/Properties";
                    };
                };
ServerRelativeUrl = "/SiteCollectionImages";
TimeCreated = "2014-04-25T12:54:44Z";
TimeLastModified = "2015-01-13T11:08:47Z";
UniqueId = "bffe7ef4-b242-4b13-990b-fcd00e7617af";
WelcomePage = "";
"__metadata" = {
         id = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')";
         type = "SP.Folder";
         uri = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/SiteCollectionImages')";
                };
```

Comment: I think I found a way to resolve the problem. Using KQL makes the job although it doesn't returns all the information that I need: http://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary'.

Comment: On the other hand, using Lists and filters operations I found another way that could make the job but it is not filtering correctly. The way I'm talking about is using the format: http://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists?filter=BaseTemplate eq 101. I could make the filtering on the client side, but it makes little sense. If I find a better option I'll put it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Although it's not perfect since it stills show some System folders, it filters most of them. Using following query does the job:

`https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists?$filter=BaseTemplate+eq+101`